# Is it safe to assume an image rotation manipulates the height and width exactly?

Tags: c#, bitmap

Say I have the following code for an image that's 200x100 or any arbitrary size really:

```
Image image = Bitmap.FromFile(fileName);
image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
image.save(fileName);
```

Is it safe to assume that the output size is 100x200? That the width and height exactly swapped values? My coworker is convinced it may not be guaranteed. I think the matrix math involved is exact and reliable. Who's right? If it matters, we're working with tif images.

Comment: I've not tested it. The maths certainly supports your theory but I can't vouch for the code. Can you not just test it? I suspect your coworker might be thinkign about situations where you do 2 45 degree rotations or similar in which case I strongly suspect it won't be the same.

Comment: A question I would ask to your coworker is, "why wouldn't it be ?". Has he found a case where the rotation didn't result in an exact result? I can't think of any reason why the `RotateFlip` method wouldn't return exact results.

Comment: I would think it is safe to make that assumption.  However, if you need the guarantee, why not create a new Bitmap with the exact size you need, and then assign the rotated image with a stretch to fill.  That way you know for sure it's the expected size

Answer (score 4):

The Image.RotateFlip Method only does rotation in exact multiples of 90 degrees (0, 90, etc.)
This means after you use it, you will always end up with one of 2 results:
1. Either the width and height will remain unchanged (for example when you flip without rotation or rotate 180 degrees).
2. Or the width and height will be exact swapped values.

Bonus info:
This type of right-angle rotation is "lossless" which means the color values are preserved and the operation can be reversed without any loss of pixel values.
On the other hand, any algorithm that rotates arbitrary angles that are not multiples of 90 degrees will be a lossy algorithm. The pixel locations and/or exact color values are not guaranteed to be restored by doing a counter-rotation.

Comment: This is how I thought it worked, but I had no supporting facts. My coworker was 3x my age and thought he knew better.